# Pegar retorno de async function em arquivo externo

Tags: node.js, async, promises, async-await

Tenho 2 arquivos, em ambos uso async / await e retorno uma promisse.
Até aí tudo bem.
Mas minha dúvida está em como chamá-los no Controller.
Estou conseguindo retornar todas as receitas, porém, não estou conseguindo adicionar o parametro **gif** no retorno do objeto na API.
Tentei passar await dentro da propriedade *gif: await* mas não consegui sucesso.

[image: Imsomnia]

```
const getRecipes = require('../services/recipePuppy');
const getGifFromRecipe = require('../services/giphy');


module.exports = {
    async getRecipes(request, response) {
        const clientRequest = request.query;

        const ingredientsList = clientRequest.i.split(',');

        const recipesResponse = await getRecipes.getRecipesFromIngredients(ingredientsList);

        if (recipesResponse) {
            response.json({
                keywords: ingredientsList,
                recipes: recipesResponse.results.map((recipe) => {
                    return {
                        title: recipe.title,
                        ingredients: recipe.ingredients,
                        link: recipe.href,
                        // gif: como obter o GIF?
                    }
                })
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Código do service giphy:

```
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports = {
    async getGif(search) {
        const response = await axios.default.get(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=${process.env.GIPHY_API}&q=${search}&limit=1&offset=0&rating=g&lang=${process.env.GIPHY_LANGUAGE}`);

        return response.data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi direito de onde viria o `search` para o `getGif`, mas supondo que fosse um campo da própria receita. Eu faria algo mais ou menos assim:

```js
const bluebird = require('bluebird');

const getRecipes = require('../services/recipePuppy');
const getGifFromRecipe = require('../services/giphy');

module.exports = {
  async getRecipes(request, response) {
    const clientRequest = request.query;
    const ingredientsList = clientRequest.i.split(',');

    const recipesResponse = await getRecipes.getRecipesFromIngredients(ingredientsList);

    if (recipesResponse) {                
      const res = await bluebird.map(recipesResponse.results, async (recipe) => {
        const gif = await getGifFromRecipe.getGif(recipe.search);
        return {
          title: recipe.title,
          ingredients: recipe.ingredients,
          link: recipe.href,
          gif,
        };
      }, { concurrency: 10 });
    
      response.json(res);
    }
  }
}
```

Utilizei o [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) pois facilita muito essas operações com Promises. O uso do parâmetro `concurrency` ali é opcional, mas é bem legal, pois possibilita paralelizar as chamadas ao serviço externo que obtém os gifs, o que agiliza bastante o tempo de resposta.

Caso o uso do Bluebird seja impossível, a solução seria fazer um `map` das receitas para um array de `Promises` de `getGif`, depois um `await` em um `Promise.all` desse array, e por último, a geração da resposta. Posso tentar botar um exemplo desse modelo aqui também, caso seja necessário.